# Linear nonhomogeneous recurrence relations with constant coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, recursion

> Find the general formula for:
> $$n a_n - (5n - 5)a_{n-1} = 0,\;a_1 = 10$$

Hello! I tried to rewrite the general term so I would have a homogeneous linear recursion and a polynomial, but I could't find a way to solve this. Could someone help me a little, please?

Comment: Hint: $b_n=na_n$ then $b_n-5b_{n-1}=0$

Comment: It worked, thank you!

Comment: And what exactly is non-homogeneous, here?